# Dalvik - local variable type mismatch when adding java file to project - Without proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, dalvik

My android project compiles and builds fine, however, when I'm adding NanoHTTPD java file (a pure java 1 file http server) I am getting the following error when launching (without proguard).

```
[2013-03-20 23:28:56 - test] Dx 
EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
[2013-03-20 23:28:56 - test] Dx local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type int using a local variable of type java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.

[2013-03-20 23:28:56 - test] Dx ...at bytecode offset 0000009d
locals[0000]: Lcom/my/android/test/NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession;
locals[0001]: Ljava/io/InputStream;
locals[0002]: I
locals[0003]: [B
locals[0004]: I
locals[0005]: I
locals[0006]: I
locals[0007]: 
locals[0008]: 
locals[0009]: 
locals[000a]: 
locals[000b]: 
locals[000c]: 
locals[000d]: 
locals[000e]: 
locals[000f]: 
locals[0010]: 
locals[0011]: 
locals[0012]: 
locals[0013]: 
locals[0014]: 
locals[0015]: 
locals[0016]: 
locals[0017]: 
locals[0018]: 
locals[0019]: 
locals[001a]: 
locals[001b]: [I
...while working on block 009d
...while working on method run:()V
...while processing run ()V
...while processing com/my/android/test/NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.class

[2013-03-20 23:28:56 - test] Dx 
EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
[2013-03-20 23:28:56 - test] Dx local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type int. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.

[2013-03-20 23:28:56 - test] Dx ...at bytecode offset 000002cd
locals[0000]: Lcom/my/android/test/NanoHTTPD;
locals[0001]: Ljava/lang/String;
locals[0002]: Ljava/util/Properties;
locals[0003]: Ljava/io/File;
locals[0004]: I
locals[0005]: Lcom/my/android/test/NanoHTTPD$Response;
locals[0006]: Ljava/io/File;
locals[0007]: [Ljava/lang/String;
locals[0008]: Ljava/lang/String;
locals[0009]: 
locals[000a]: 
locals[000b]: 
locals[000c]: 
locals[000d]: 
locals[000e]: 
locals[000f]: 
locals[0010]: 
locals[0011]: 
locals[0012]: 
locals[0013]: 
locals[0014]: 
locals[0015]: 
locals[0016]: [I
stack[top0]: Ljava/lang/String;
...while working on block 02cd
...while working on method serveFile:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava/io/File;Z)Lcom/my/android/test/NanoHTTPD$Response;
...while processing serveFile (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava/io/File;Z)Lcom/my/android/test/NanoHTTPD$Response;
...while processing com/my/android/test/NanoHTTPD.class
```

This only happens on the current project and did not happen when I used NanoHTTPD on other projects.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was an eclipse plugin that did it - CodePro BY GOOGLE!
Their code coverage tool somehow caused the above error (maybe has something to do with emma, but that's just a guess).

Comment: Hi inistel, please i too have same issue. please suggest me if you have any solution. like what to do to resolve this issue.